# "x" and 'x' , x <- 5 and x = 5 are same in R?

Tags: r

It seems output is same when I use any of the two. Is there any difference between them?

```
x <- "hello"
x <- 'hello'
x = "hello"
x = 'hello'
```

It seems all are giving same output. Is there difference between them? and when to use them?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your examples, the answer is yes. But see notes below:

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html

> Single and double quotes delimit character constants. They can be used
>   interchangeably but double quotes are preferred (and character
>   constants are printed using double quotes), so single quotes are
>   normally only used to delimit character constants containing double
>   quotes.

http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2008/12/use-equals-or-arrow-for-assignment.html

> A little history before we continue: when the R language (and S before
>   it) was first created, <- was the only choice of assignment operator. 
>   This is a hangover from the language APL, where the arrow notation was
>   used to distinguish assignment (assign the value 3 to x) from equality
>   (is x equal to 3?). (Professor Ripley reminds me that on APL keyboards
>   there was an actual key on the keyboard with the arrow symbol on it,
>   so the arrow was a single keystroke back then. The same was true of
>   the AT&T terminals first used for the predecessors of S as described
>   in the Blue Book.) However many modern languages (such as C, for
>   example) use = for assignment, so beginners using R often found the
>   arrow notation cumbersome, and were prone to use = by mistake.  But R
>   uses = for yet another purpose: associating function arguments with
>   values (as in pnorm(1, sd=2), to set the standard deviation to 2). To
>   make things easier for new users familiar with languages like C, R
>   added the capability in 2001 to also allow = be used as an assignment
>   operator, on the basis that the intent (assignment or association) is
>   usually clear by context.  So, x = 3
>
> clearly means "assign 3 to x", whereas
>
> f(x = 3)
>
> clearly means "call function f, setting the argument x to 3".

Comment: "Yes" to the question in title (are they same) or to the question in body (are they different)? And equals sign cannot be used everywhere.

Comment: And I found out recently while learning that only '<-' works while replacing where as '= 'does not work. Is it true that only '<-'  works for replacing?''